# Ember.js get 2 nested models in one route in asynchronous way

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, ember.js, promise

I have 2 calls to server, which proceed a long time (10-20 seconds). I need update information on page after first request (doesn't matters which) was finished. After second request finished - i need also update part of page.

How can be realised, because I've tried realise with Promises

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
      return Ember.$.getJSON('url').then(firstMethod).then(secondMethod)
    }
})
```

but it doesn't work, because secondMethod will be executed after firstMethod will be finished.

Also I tried use this code:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      first_data: Ember.$.getJSON('url1'),
      second_data: Ember.$.getJSON('url2') 
    });
  }
});
```

But I have the same trouble - data will be return after 2 calls will be finished.

How run asynchronously these 2 requests and do independent update part of data on page ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the [PromiseProxyMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html) to create object proxies that will automatically update when your promises resolve. Something like this:

```
model: function() {
    return Ember.Object.create({
        first_data: Ember.ObjectProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin, {
            promise: Ember.$.getJSON('url1')
        }),
        second_data: Ember.ObjectProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin, {
            promise: Ember.$.getJSON('url2')
        })
    });
}
```

Ember will watch your model and your two data properties for updates. Before the promises are resolved, every property asked for will return `undefined`. But when the promises resolve, the PromiseProxyMixin will trigger an update on the proxies, which will in turn trigger an update on all of the properties you're watching.